# ¿Por qué no se carga el contenido de mi Custom Post Type?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
                $las_ofertas = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type' => 'oferta',
                    'posts_per_page' => 5
                ));

                $ciudad = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'oferta_ciudad', true);
                $fecha = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'oferta_date', true);
                $descripcion = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'oferta_descripcion', true);

                if ( $las_ofertas->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $las_ofertas->have_posts() ) : $las_ofertas->the_post(); ?>

                        <article class="al70">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <?php if( $ciudad ) {  ?> <p><?php echo ($ciudad); ?></p>
                            <?php  } else {?> <p>La oferta no especifica la ciudad en la que desarrollará el trabajo.</p> <?php } ?>

                            <?php if( $fecha ) {  ?> <p><?php echo ($fecha); ?></p>
                            <?php  } else {?> <p>La oferta no especifica la fecha de inicio.</p> <?php } ?>

                            <?php if( $descripcion ) {  ?>
                            <h3>Descripción:</h3>
                            <p><?php echo ($descripcion); ?></p>
                            <?php  } else {?> <p>La empresa no ofrece detalles del trabajo.</p> <?php } ?>

                            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn"><?php _e('Ver oferta...') ?></a></p>

                        </article>  <!-- article -->

                    <?php endwhile;
                } else { ?>
                    <p>No existen ofertas para mostrar.</p>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata();
```

Cuando lo veo en el front-end, sólo aparece el título de la Oferta, mas no el contenido de la misma, es decir, la función ´get_post_meta();´ no recoge los valores del CPT.

[image: No se muestra el contenido del CPT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al patecer tienes mal ubicadas las varables, deberian estar dentro del loop y encerradas entre una etiquta php. Te beria quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php $las_ofertas = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'oferta',
'posts_per_page' => 5
)); ?>  

<?php if ( $las_ofertas->have_posts() ) {
while ( $las_ofertas->have_posts() ) : $las_ofertas->the_post(); ?>

<?php
$ciudad = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'oferta_ciudad', true);
$fecha = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'oferta_date', true);
$descripcion = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'oferta_descripcion', true);
?>

<article class="al70">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php if( $ciudad ) {  ?> <p><?php echo ($ciudad); ?></p>
    <?php  } else {?> <p>La oferta no especifica la ciudad en la que desarrollará el trabajo.</p> <?php } ?>

    <?php if( $fecha ) {  ?> <p><?php echo ($fecha); ?></p>
    <?php  } else {?> <p>La oferta no especifica la fecha de inicio.</p> <?php } ?>

    <?php if( $descripcion ) {  ?>
    <h3>Descripción:</h3>
    <p><?php echo ($descripcion); ?></p>
    <?php  } else {?> <p>La empresa no ofrece detalles del trabajo.</p> <?php } ?>

    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn"><?php _e('Ver oferta...') ?> </a></p>

</article>  <!-- article -->
```

No existen ofertas para mostrar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, llegué a la misma conclusión con los intentos y esa era la solución. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Eso pasa por que tienes el `get_post_meta`fuera del loop, debería quedar algo como:

```
...
while ( $las_ofertas->have_posts() ) : $las_ofertas->the_post(); 
 $ciudad = get_post_meta($las_ofertas->post->ID, 'oferta_ciudad', true);
 $fecha = get_post_meta($las_ofertas->post->ID, 'oferta_date', true);
 $descripcion = get_post_meta($las_ofertas->post->ID, 'oferta_descripcion', true);
...
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, llegué a la misma conclusión con los intentos y esa fué la solución. Saludos